# Painting Cells in Grid

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a JSfiddle set up here. I'm drawing a canvas grid and want to allow a user to select a color and 'paint' the grid cells like pixel art. Can someone point me in the right direction?

http://jsfiddle.net/g51bx1nb/

```
var c_canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var context = c_canvas.getContext("2d");

for (var x = 0.5; x < 501; x += 20) {
context.moveTo(x, 0);
context.lineTo(x, 381);
}

for (var y = 0.5; y < 381; y += 20) {
context.moveTo(0, y);
context.lineTo(500, y);
}


context.strokeStyle = "#ddd";
context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this should get you closer.

```
 function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }
function getNearestSquare(position) {
 var x = position.x;
    var y = position.y;
if (x < 0 || y < 0) return null;
    x = (Math.floor(x / 20) * 20) + 0.5
    y = (Math.floor(y / 20) * 20) + 0.5
    return {x: x, y: y};
}
$(c_canvas).click(function(evt) {
    var pos = getNearestSquare(getMousePos(c_canvas, evt));
    if (pos != null) {
        context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
        context.fillRect(pos.x,pos.y,20,20);
    }
});
```

I tried this out on your fiddle, adding this JS code gives you an on click event that'll let you click and paint an area the size of one of your squares red, you just need to use the fill style as a variable that the user can change.

Edit:
I added the logic to find the top left.

Comment: This answers my question perfect, thank you! One small additional question: I am trying to count how many squares of each color exist and have been using the document.click event but it also registers clicks outside of the canvas. Any tips?

Comment: Got it by changing to $(c_canvas).click(function(evt) {